# Clang and Intel fail to compile this CRTP code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, crtp

I have written a small library that use a lot of C++11 metaprogramming techniques and CRTP, and it compiles well with g++ 4.7.2

Now, I try to compile it with Intel icpc 13.0.0.079 and it generates several hundreds of errors. So I try to isolate the problems one after another.

So, first, consider this code, that compiles with no problem under g++ 4.7.2

```
#include <iostream>

template<template<typename> class Crtp, typename Type>
struct Base {};

template<typename Type>
struct Derived : public Base<Derived, Type>
{
    Derived(): Base<Derived, Type>() {;}
};

int main()
{
    Derived<int> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Both icpc and clang fail to compile this code:

```
test_crtp.cpp(26): error: type "Derived<Type>::Derived" is not a class template
      Derived(): Base<Derived, Type>() {;}
                      ^

test_crtp.cpp(26): error: "Base" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Derived<int>"
      Derived(): Base<Derived, Type>() {;}
                 ^
          detected during instantiation of "Derived<Type>::Derived() [with Type=int]" at line 31

compilation aborted for test_crtp.cpp (code 2)
```

So is it a bug in intel and clang, or in g++ ? If it's in intel and clang, do you think that it will be solved in a future version ?

Comment: It's a good question, but usually CRTP doesn't bother with a template-template parameter, but just has the Derived class pass the type.  `template<typename Derived> struct Base;  template<typename T> struct Derived: Base< Derived<T> > { ... };` is more normal.

Comment: ...if you wanted to propagate `Type`, may be you can have a `typedef` in `Derived` which exposes it...

Comment: The identifier `Derived` names, inside its own class, the complete type `Derived<Whatever>`. This is called an *injected* class name. I think this is a bug with GCC.

Comment: + for good question, I want see a definitive answer too

Comment: @Xeo : and is there a way to get the non-complete type inside the class ?

Comment: Only through fully qualifying it like Marc says.

Comment: @Dave S and @Nim: you cannot always have a nested typedef inside Derived. E.g. `Derived` is not a complete type yet when you try to use it inside `Base`. Vincent's use of a template-template parameter is required if you need the inner typedef already in the Base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the class `Derived`, the name `Derived` refers to the (instantiated) class, not the class template. Try `Base< ::Derived, Type>` instead (be careful to leave a space between < and ::).

Comment: Note: the reason for the space is that `<:` could be interpreted as a [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), and thus `<::` would be seen as `[:` after preprocessing...

Comment: In C++11, you can just write `<::Derived`, the `<:` is not interpreted as a digraph in a template argument list.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Also note that that is only true for C++ before C++11 (or GCC < 4.8)=

Comment: @Xeo: Ah thanks! I stumbled across it a couple times and it's damn frustrating :(

Comment: I've never used this syntax, so could you describe the exact meaning of "::" in this case (or post a link to a tutorial/explanation of it).

Comment: It is the same :: as in std::vector. With nothing in front, it means the global namespace.

Comment: Ok, so if my class is in a namespace, I need to type `Base< mynamespace::Derived, Type>` ?

Comment: Yes. (now filling to 15 characters min)

Comment: So that's a bug of g++ ? Do you think I should post it on the bug tracker ?

Comment: Yes please (look first if you can't find an existing PR about the same). Worst that can happen is they'll give you a better answer than mine ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In section 9.2.3 of **C++ Template the Complete Guide** ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842)), there is a discussion on Injected Class Names. To quote:

> Class templates also have injected class names. However, they're
>   stranger than ordinary injected class names: They can be followed by
>   template arguments (in which case they are injected class template
>   names), but if they are not followed by template arguments they
>   represent the class with its parameters as its arguments (or, for a
>   partial specialization, its specialization arguments). This explains
>   the following situation:

```
template<template<typename> class TT> 
class X {};

template<typename T> 
class C 
{
    Ca;        // OK: same as ''C<T> a;''
    C<void> b; // OK
    X<C> c;    // ERROR: C without a template argument list
               // does not denote a template
    X<::C> d;  // ERROR: <: is an alternative token for [
    X< ::C> e; // OK: the space between < and :: is required
}
```

> Note how the unqualified name refers to the injected name and is not
>   considered the name of the template if it is not followed by a list of
>   template arguments. To compensate, we can force the name of the
>   template to be found by using the file scope qualifier ::. This works,
>   but we must then be careful not to create a so-called digraph token
>   <:, which is interpreted as a left bracket. Although relatively rare,
>   such errors result in perplexing diagnostics.

So what happens in your code is that `Base<Derived, Type>` is being interpreted as `Base<Derived<Type>, Type>` which is ill-formed. Therefore you need to use the scope qualifier `::` with a space between the `<` to avoid a digraph.